# How to keep cursor in its place in MS word?

Tags: microsoft-word, scrolling, cursor, mouse-cursor

I am an MS word 2013 user; in my previous version of MS word, when I was writing something and meanwhile I wanted to check a reference at the end of my document, I moved the scroll by mouse and check that reference and for coming back to the previous point, I just went on writing.

Since cursor didn't move, I automatically found my previous place in document. But the current version of MS word (2013) has a feature by which cursor moves to the place of scroll after scrolling. I would like to turn off this feature; what's your suggestion?

Comment: My copy of Word 2013 doesn't do that (it behaves as you describe, the cursor stays put while scrolling with the mouse wheel). So if there is an option, it's off by default.  Are oyu using the same computer you used with pervious versions of Word, or is this a new computer as well? what kind of Mouse do you have? Does it behave the same way in other editors, like Notepad?

Comment: Are you sure ALL you are doing is scrolling down to look at the reference and then scrolling back up?  You're not clicking or pressing anything during those actions?

Comment: I answered you in the comments of the accepted answer; but I suppose that you didn't see

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 For your extra questions: I didn't changed any option; my MS word licence is something like classroom. My previous word was not 2013 (as I explained). I use external mouse. I don't have such problem in notepad. All what I am doing is scrolling down to look reference; but not scrolling up; because my document is very large and it is hard to find the first place. Though, finally, I must comeback somehow! and as I explained, below, I do not press anything.

Comment: Got it. If you stick an @ and a name, it will notify us of the comment. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems it's a feature called ***Smart Cursoring*** . Details from [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/editor-options-advanced-0b2b5644-41e2-42c4-990b-60ca36615600):

> When smart cursoring is turned on, you can press the LEFT ARROW, RIGHT ARROW, UP ARROW, or DOWN ARROW key to use the cursor on the page currently in view, not at its position prior to scrolling, as long as no content is selected at the original position. To turn on smart cursoring, click Options on the Tools menu and then, on the Edit tab, select the Use smart cursoring check box.

So, in your case, click *Options* on the *File* menu and then, on the *Advanced* tab, **deselect** the *Use smart cursoring* check box.

Comment: There is no "Tools" menu in Word 2013. ;) It's File -> Options -> Advanced -> Use Smart Cursoring.  And mine is turned on, and the cursor doesn't follow the scroll wheel as the OP is describing, he doesn't say he's pressing any arrow keys. Actually changing the option has no effect on how the cursor behave when I scroll with the mouse wheel.

Comment: I don't press any arrow key; but note that it doesn't follow while scrolling after finishing the scrolling it will move there.

Comment: @hossayni Mine just does not behave that way.  You can scroll and then let it sit all day, and the cursor will stay where it originally was before scrolling.  Did this answer actually fix it for you? Deselecting that option made it stop?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 yes; it fixed my problem; also, please look at my comment, above.

Comment: @hossayni Weird. Glad it worked, but it seems strange since that's not what the option says it is, and it doesn't behave as you explained in your question on my Windows 7/Word 2013 machine, regardless of that option's setting.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I suppose that you don't behave as I do. keep your cursor in the middle of your long document; then move the scroll by mouse to the end; then let the scroll stay there and leave the mouse button. Now, push one of the arrow keys on your keyboard. I exactly have Win7 x64 MS office 2013 x64, desktop computer.